# Can't make keras.models.Model with feature_column to estimator model. TypeError: missing argument: 'feature_columns'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

With tf 1.14.0
I'am trying to make a keras model with feature columns to an estimator model.
But it not work, how can I solve it?
My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import dot
from tensorflow import feature_column

numerical_columns = ['age','fare']
feature_columns = []

def make_feature_column(numerical_columns):
    feature_columns = []
    feature_layer_inputs = {}
    # numeric cols
    for header in numerical_columns:
        header_str = str(header)
        feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header_str))
        feature_layer_inputs[header_str] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header_str)
    return feature_columns,feature_layer_inputs

feature_columns,feature_layer_inputs = make_feature_column(numerical_columns)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns,trainable=False)(feature_layer_inputs)
x = Dense(units=2048, activation='relu')(feature_layer)
x = Dense(units=1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(units=200, activation='relu',name='user_vec')(x)
item_input = Input((200,), name='item_vec')
x = Lambda(lambda t: t / tf.linalg.norm(t, ord=1))(x)

x = dot([x, item_input], axes=-1)
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

feature_layers = feature_layer_inputs.values()
inputs = [v for v in feature_layers]
inputs.append(item_input)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=main_output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'main_output': 1.})

estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
```

But it return an Type error, i can't understand the error.
And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lideyang/PycharmProjects/NewUserSort/test.py", line 42, in <module>
    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/estimator/__init__.py", line 73, in model_to_estimator
    config=config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py", line 450, in model_to_estimator
    config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py", line 318, in _save_first_checkpoint
    custom_objects)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py", line 201, in _clone_and_build_model
    optimizer_iterations=global_step)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 538, in clone_and_build_model
    clone = clone_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 326, in clone_model
    model, input_tensors=input_tensors, layer_fn=clone_function)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 154, in _clone_functional_model
    new_layer = layer_fn(layer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 54, in _clone_layer
    return layer.__class__.from_config(layer.get_config())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 446, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```

When I don't use feature columns, but use Inputlayer such as 'user_input = Input((300,), name='user_input')', it works.  how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be resolved once you have upgraded version of tensorflow to `1.15` or `2.x`.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import dot
from tensorflow import feature_column

numerical_columns = ['age','fare']
feature_columns = []

def make_feature_column(numerical_columns):
    feature_columns = []
    feature_layer_inputs = {}
    # numeric cols
    for header in numerical_columns:
        header_str = str(header)
        feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header_str))
        feature_layer_inputs[header_str] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header_str)
    return feature_columns,feature_layer_inputs

feature_columns,feature_layer_inputs = make_feature_column(numerical_columns)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns,trainable=False)(feature_layer_inputs)
x = Dense(units=2048, activation='relu')(feature_layer)
x = Dense(units=1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(units=200, activation='relu',name='user_vec')(x)
item_input = Input((200,), name='item_vec')
x = Lambda(lambda t: t / tf.linalg.norm(t, ord=1))(x)

x = dot([x, item_input], axes=-1)
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

feature_layers = feature_layer_inputs.values()
inputs = [v for v in feature_layers]
inputs.append(item_input)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=main_output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'main_output': 1.})

estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
```

Output:

```
2.4.0
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpwa8ialaq
INFO:tensorflow:Using the Keras model provided.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:434: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': '/tmp/tmpwa8ialaq', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_checkpoint_save_graph_def': True, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
```